# Passing number from controller to view in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to pass a number from my controller to my blade and running into a snag. Looking for an assist.

Here is my Controller (BulkSmsController.php)

```
public function getTwilioNumberUserID(Request $request)
{
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $company_id = Auth::user()->company_id;
    if (!$company_id) {
        $company_id = Auth::user()->id;
    }

    $twilio_number_recall = User::where('id', $company_id)->first()->mobile_no;
    return view('company.bulksms.twilio_number_recall', compact('twilio_number_recall'));
}
```

Here is my Blade (bulksms.blade.php)

```
<label>From:</label>
                        <input style="padding: 1.8rem;" type='text' class="form-control" name='from' value="{{twilio_number_recall}}" />
```

Here is my Route (web.php)

```
Route::get('/company/bulksms', 'BulkSmsController@getTwilioNumberUserID')->name('company.bulksms');
```

I'm getting the following error:

*View [company.bulksms.twilio_number_recall] not found.*

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says that it cannot find the view you passed in the controller at `return view()`; So it means `company.bulksms.twilio_number_recall` this is not correct. You can copy the path from content root of `bulksms.blade.php` and paste it in there. You don't have to include `resources.views`

Edit: Since your blade is named `bulksms.blade.php` i suppose this will be the right path `return view('company.bulksms', compact('twilio_number_recall'));`

Comment: Also you can remove the `$user_id = Auth::user()->id;` because the variable `$user_id` is not being used

Comment: thanks! but im getting the following error now: Use of undefined constant twilio_number_recall - assumed 'twilio_number_recall' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) (View: /var/www/html/laravel/resources/views/company/bulksms.blade.php)

Comment: in the blade you forgot the `$`. 
`<input style="padding: 1.8rem;" type='text' class="form-control" name='from' value="{{ $twilio_number_recall}}" />`